# How to define an empty-value attribute in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I need to add an attribute to MANIFEST.MF with an empty value. This doesn't work:

```
Foo-Attrib:
```

`java.util.jar.Manifest` can't load such a file and throws an exception. What is a possible workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my reading of the JAR file spec, you can have an attribute with an empty value.  But there must be a space character after the ':'.

(The relevant section of the spec is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value_pairs_and_Sections).)